# Почему не срабатывает скрипт, обрабатывающий отправку данных с формы?(

Tags: javascript, jquery, form

Помогите, у меня уже мозг кипит от обилия работы, а я застряла на какой-то слишком очевидной ошибке, чтобы ее заметить.

Есть простейшая форма

```
<form id="form_add_sellers" method="post">                  
      <input placeholder="E-mail" type="text" name="email" id="subscription_email">
      <button id="subscriber_reg_submit" type="submit">ПОЛУЧАТЬ</button>
</form>
```

Есть блок, выводящийся после успешной отправки данных

```
<div id="shadow"></div>    
<div id="subscriber_popup_after_submit">
         <div id="popup_close">X</div>
         <h2>Поздравляем! Вы были успешно подписаны</h2>
</div>
```

Есть скрипт, который на нажатие кнопки вообще никак не реагирует. Я проверяла в отладчике гугл-браузера, эта функция тупо никогда не вызывается

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Добавление нового подписчика
    $('#form_add_sellers').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $email = $('#subscription_email').val();
        $.post('/?func=add', {email: $email}, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data == 1) {
                $('#shadow').show();
                $('#subscriber_popup_after_submit').show();
            }else if (data == 2) {
                alert('Некорректно заполнено поле email');
            }else if (data == 0){
                alert('Пользователь с таким email уже существует');
            }                               
        }, 'text').fail(function () {
            alert('Ошибка! Данные не сохранены, перезагрузите страницу и попробуйте снова!');
        });
    });
    $('body').on('click', '#popup_close, #shadow', function() {
        $('#shadow').hide();
        $('#subscriber_popup_after_submit').hide();
    });
});
```

Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

На странице подключена библиотека jquery

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

ХЭЛП МИ, плиз!(((

Comment: что именно не срабатывает - отправка формы или submit? Последнее должно работать судя по коду. Как в отладчике проверяли?

Comment: Во-первых, я ставлю внутрь тела функции брейкпойнт, во-вторых, как видите, там есть тестовый вывод данных в консоль, который не происходит, а в третьих, даже если вызов функции post срабатывает неверно (а он скорее всего срабатывает неверно), то алерт с ошибкой все же должен быть

Comment: Ну тогда вам должно быть очевидно , что раз никакой реакции на нажатие нет, значит обработчик события навешивается когда когда целевого элемента еще не существует.

Comment: вот ваш код - всё нормально отрабатывает https://jsfiddle.net/upnf4hwg/

Comment: Перенесла скрипт из инлайна во внешнюю ссылку, подключаемую в шапке, все заработало. Хотя из того, что тесты на скорость страниц всегда ругаются на внешние скрипты, блокирующие загрузку страниц, всегда думала, что инлайн скрипт сработает позже...

Answer (score 0):

Переместила скрипт из инлайна во внешний файл и включила в конце head - и все заработало...